# What is the area between two first order taylor series approximations as they become closer to eachother

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let's say that $y=\sin{x}$. Then the first order taylor series approximation about $c$ is $g(x)=\sin{(c)}+\cos{(c)}(x-c)$. Note that this is also equivalent to the line tangent to the curve $\sin{x}$ with point $(c,\sin{c})$ and slope $\cos c$.

Now, imagine you take two lines: $g(k)$, and $g(k+\delta)$, letting $\delta$ go to $0$ from the right. It seems obvious to me that this limit implies that the two lines will in fact be the same. And in that sense, $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0^+}\int_a^b(g(x)-g(x+\delta))\ \text{dx}=0$ for finite $a$ and $b$.

My question is then, what can we say about
$$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty(g(k)-g(k+\delta))\ \text{dk}$$
My intuition thinks it may end up being $f(c)=\sin c$.

Comment: Taylor series are local approximations.  In most cases it does not make sense to look at them far from the point where you make the expansion.  In the case of analytic functions, of which $\sin x$ is one, the infinite Taylor series converges to the function over the whole real line.  Even in that case, the higher order terms become more important as the distance from $c$ increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer may be a little disappointing.  Observe that
$$g(x)-g(x+\delta)=-\delta\cos(c), $$
which is constant in $x$.  So the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)-g(x+\delta)\ dx=\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^A g(x)-g(x+\delta)\ dx=\lim_{A\to\infty}-2\delta A\cos(c)$$
converges only if $\cos(c)=0$.  Thus, it either makes no sense to talk about the limit as $\delta\to0^+$, or the limit is trivially $0$.

Comment: What about when $y'(c)=0$? I guess that's the only time we could say the integral is $0$ since $\lim_{A\rightarrow\infty}{-2\delta A\cdot 0}=0$.

Comment: @WillSherwood Ahh thanks.  I will edit.

Comment: One other question. Since $\delta$ is approaching $0$ and $A$ is approaching $\infty$, shouldn't this be some sort of indeterminate form $(0\cdot \infty)$? What is your proof that the limit is divergent?

Comment: We take the limit as $A\to\infty$ first, when $\delta$ is fixed. The limits aren't taken simultaneously.

Comment: I now believe this answer is incorrect. $g(x+\delta)$ is not in fact $\sin(c)+\cos(c)(x-c)$ but is actually $\sin(c+\delta)+\cos(c+\delta)(x-\delta-c)$. Because the two functions are completely different, I should have stated it as $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$... $g(x)$ and $g(x+\delta)$ only differ by a constant, but upon further analysis they will definitely have a different slope. Because of this, unfortunately I have to remove the 'correct answer' mark until it is corrected.

Comment: You can see a visual proof that it is actually 0 here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u99wskfsnc

Comment: Firstly, that is a different question.  If you want a different answer, ask a different question.

Comment: Secondly,  the difference between $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ as you now define it is still a linear function..  The integral over $\mathbb{R}$ will still be infinite unless $\delta=0$, and so it still makes no sense to talk about the limit as $\delta\to0^+$